# Buffer -over river line with 20m over

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, buffer

I want to make a buffer from the river line with only the points that have over 20 m (elevation) from river line. (I hope you understand:D).
How can I do that?

### [image]

[image]

Here is the picture....I want only the consecutive points over the river line :)

I use ArcMap 9.3. I've made offset points (from 50m to 50m) of river line from 200m to 200m. I interpolate with DEM and I query the points with 20m over the river line elevation...But I have a problem: I have a lot of points with 20m over, and I want only the consecutives one. How can I do this?

[image: Point after query - elevation over 20 m]
All the points with 20m over the river line
---[image: Only the points I am interested]
The points I want

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using to try and do this, please?

Comment: As a new user I recommend that you take the [Tour] and review [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) You now seem to have sufficient details here to enable your original question to be progressed so I recommend that you copy/paste these details into that question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122688/i-want-to-query-only-the-consecutive-offset).  If you then tidy up its title and content I think you should be back on track to attracting potential answerers.

Comment: I see that you have now deleted your original question, so as an expedient, I'm going to re-open this one.  Please take the opportunity to edit it so that it reads as clearly as possible for any potential answerers.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not yet understand what you are planning to do. Could you draw the desired result to the sketch? What does buffering to do with the task?

Comment: I wanr to keep only the consecutive points along the river that have the elevation over 20 m over the river elevation. You can see in the image that I want to delete the points from "I don't want these points"...Offset points is from 50 m to 50m...

Comment: Please edit your question to try and make what you are asking clearer there rather than creating a comment trail that may or may not be looked at or understood by potential answerers.  I too cannot understand the connection between your picture and your description.  Perhaps labelling the points with their elevation values may make it clearer why you do not want those points.

Comment: Are the points extracted from a cross section line you created but not displaying? If so just select the cross sections that intersect your network use that selection to select the points then reverse the selection and that should leave you with the points that are just floating around nothing to do with the network.

Comment: not the answer I was looking for. I can query after Offset (points from 50m to 50m) something like that: Offset>-1000 and Offset<1000 ... but It's not exactly....